# how can i get access to user model data with orm

Tags: php, laravel, orm, model

I am trying to make a forum I have done thread CRUD and comment,
 I want to display the name of the user that commented I think I have messed up the relationship

I have tried adding the right eloquent relationship but I can't seem to understand how it works

user model

```
public function threads(){
        return $this->hasMany(Thread::class);
    }
```

thread model

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
```

comment thread

```
public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

display view for rendering

```
 @foreach ($thread->comments as $comment)            
            <div class="media">
                <img src="#" class="mr-3" alt="...">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">{{ $comment->user->name }}</h5>
                    {{$comment->body}}
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

I expect to be able to access the user name and other user data for thread and comment modal

but I get error

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\myforum\resources\views\thread\single.blade.php)

[image]

Comment: Missing a relation from `User` to `Comments`?

Comment: how can i add it

Comment: Like you did with the `threads()` relation. (A user has many threads but he also has many comments, I think)

Comment: not working just tried that

Comment: add this in comment model `public function user()
{
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}` and also add this in you fetch query using `with(['comments.user'])`

Comment: if comments have the `user_id` then it will work